# 'Full screen' menu for Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am quite new to android development and I have the need to present the user with a 'full screen' menu, instead of an options or context menus.

I thought about using a ListView filled with an ArrayAdapter, but I don't know if there's a smarter/easier way.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a ListView sounds good to me.

You could make your activity full screen (see http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/10/21/making-an-fullscreen-activity-in-android/), put a listview in it and fill it with your items I don't see any problem in this way of doing.

Comment: Should I use a menu resource? Could I? Thanks!

Comment: If you mean putting the menu into a resource (**xml**) hell yeah! UI definition should **always** remain into resources to have a nice pattern and code